# Intercepting only GET Requests using HandlerInterceptorAdapter class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, interceptor

Is it possible to intercept only GET requests in a spring boot application?

The method addPathPatterns() does not solve my purpose.

I want to exclude or include requests to be intercepted on the basis of their Request Method.

For example:

1. Intercept only GET requests
2. Intercept only GET and POST requests.

The application is going to receive GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests.

Comment: Well, intercept them all, and do nothing in the interceptor if the request method isn't GET.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I want to do. I am trying to find out if there's a way to completely exclude the requests to be intercepted based on the request method.

Comment: There isn't. You can only specify the path not the method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can.
You will intercept all of methods but you will have to filter them using `getMethod()` from request. This is the javadoc of it:

```
 /**
     * Returns the name of the HTTP method with which this 
     * request was made, for example, GET, POST, or PUT.
     * Same as the value of the CGI variable REQUEST_METHOD.
     *
     * @return          a <code>String</code> 
     *              specifying the name
     *              of the method with which
     *              this request was made
     */
    public String getMethod();
```